# Find the number of possible seating arrangements so that the two children can sit on either side of the mother.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A mother and her two small children join seven members of her family for dinner and they have to sit around a round table. Find the number of possible seating arrangements so that the two children can sit on either side of the mother.

The $7$ members of the family can sit around a round table in $6!$ ways. Then there are $7$ spots in between each member on the table and the mother and two children can be placed in $3!$ ways. So there are $6!*7*3!$ ways for them to sit. How does this look?

Comment: The mother and two children can be placed in $2!$ ways not $3!$, if the mother must be in the middle

Comment: "Find the number of possible seating arrangements so that the two children can sit on either side of the mother." Wouldn't this wording imply that there are $3!=6$ ways? $MC{_1}C{_2}, MC{_2}C{_1}, C{_1}C{_2}M, C_2C{_1}M, C{_1}MC{_2}, C{_2}MC{_1}$

Comment: Sitting on either side of the mother? Why is this wrong? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Many people,  including me, would read "the two children can sit on either side of the mother" as each child next to their mother, with one child on one side and the other on the other, so just $C_1MC_2,C_2MC_1$ from your list

Comment: I must be weird or something lol.

Comment: The two children can sit on either side. Child ones chooses the right side. Child two chooses the right side too. You said either side. I feel that it is ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe it should say "the children must sit next to their mom". I don't mean to be extremely pedantic, but I can see it both ways.

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, the question should be interpreted to mean that the children are seated on each side of the mother (it is hard to tend to one small child if you have to reach over the other one to do so).  Therefore, as others have indicated, there are $2!$ ways to seat the children next to their mother, which changes your answer to $6! \cdot 7 \cdot 2! = 7!2!$.

Here is another approach:

Seat the mother.  It does not matter where since, unless otherwise specified, we only care about the relative order of the people at a circular table.  We will use the mother as a reference point.  There are two ways to seat her younger child next to her and one way to seat her older child on her other side.  The remaining seven family members can be seated in $7!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table relative to the mother, which yields
$$2 \cdot 1 \cdot 7! = 2!7!$$
admissible seating arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

There are eight "units"... the mother-plus-kids-on-sides and the seven others.  Find the number of ways to place those eight units.  Then for each such way you can switch the two kids adjacent the mother, thereby doubling the number of seatings.

Comment: How are there $5$ units? There's $10$ people in total, the mother and two children join seven family members.

Comment: @ddswsd David Stork beat me to it.  Pretend that the mother and two children are handcuffed together, and that they will occupy one large sofa like chair, at the 12-oclock position of the table.  The other 7 people can be permuted in $7!$ ways around the sofa like chair, and on the sofa, the children can be permuted in $2!$ ways.

Comment: @ddswsd Then, once the seating is fixed, someone replaces the sofa like chair with 3 normal chairs for the mother and two children to sit on, with the mother remaining at the 12 o-clock position.